# VestaCP Fastcgi/Phpcgi memory limit change

Tags: php, fastcgi, centos6, memory-limit

I am using Vestacp together with Centos 6.7 when I change to phpcgi, I get a error on my domain

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 88 bytes) in /home/admin/web/....

I have already changed /etc/php.ini to 2048M memory limit, but when using phpcgi template it doesnt seem to read from the php.ini, I get 128M and dont know what file i should change the memory settings in.

I tried to search and google where to change the settings, but didnt find anything.

Vestacp using nginx/fastcgi

would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

VestaCP uses the configs located here:

```
/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php5/conf.d/*
```

More info here https://vestacp.com/docs/

PS: See this http://forum.vestacp.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=9364 also.